# Unable to get source files

Tags: yocto, bitbake, imx8

I am using imx8mnevk and I was trying to rebuild an image and removed the tmp directory.

I ran bitbake core-image-minimal but now the tmp directory doesn't seem to have a work-shared folder that is supposed to have all the source files.

I want to modify device tree but cant seem to find where they are located.

Is there a way to get the sources again or do I need to redo everything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to avoid making any modifications within the `tmp` directory (it's named `tmp` because it's internal & temporary). Specifically, avoid making source code changes there because they may get overwritten during future builds, and in some cases Yocto will fail to detect modified code under `tmp` and won't actually do what you expect.

Instead, use [devtool](https://docs.yoctoproject.org/ref-manual/devtool-reference.html) to extract and modify the source code for a package. For example:

```
devtool modify virtual/kernel
```

This will extract the kernel source into a `workspace` directory, and override the kernel recipe to use that source.

You can modify that source, build, and once you're happy with your changes, `devtool` has some commands that automatically capture your changes as a patch file and generate a `.bbappend` file in your chosen layer.

Check out [Using `devtool` to Patch the Kernel](https://docs.yoctoproject.org/kernel-dev/common.html#using-devtool-to-patch-the-kernel) in Yocto's kernel development guide for tips.

In your case, I suspect the `work-shared` directory didn't reappear because Yocto was able to use the `sstate-cache` (which is outside `tmp`) to deliver the `core-image-minimal` recipe from cache, without needing to rebuild the kernel.

Comment: Thank you so much I was looking for this. I used to make changes in tmp which I knew was incorrect but since I was unaware I had no choice kind of , now devtool helps a lot!!